# Button on a fragment won't link to another activity, no matter what I try

Tags: java, android, button, fragment

I've created my own java class fragments for a tabbed activity and everything was going well until I had to link some image buttons to other activities.

For reasons I do no understand, the code I learned to use to make buttons on other activities won't work on my fragment pages.

I've figured out how to use findViewbyId on a fragment using getView... but it still wont let me link my image button to another activity.

```
package com.example.reachv2.ui.main;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.reachv2.HelpLine;
import com.example.reachv2.R;

public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    private ImageButton button;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, false);
        button = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openHelpLine();
            }
        });
        }

    public void openHelpLine() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Frag2.this,HelpLine.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

> error: no suitable constructor found for
>   Intent(Frag2,Class)
>       constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; Frag2 cannot be converted to String)
>       constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; Frag2 cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Nothing is called in `onCreateView` after `return`. Use `onViewCreated` and initialize button there

Comment: now i get the error error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using A constructor for Intent that does not exist and the compiler is telling that in the error section.

Second I think you are using Intent to redirect to fragment, Could you try this approach?

```
NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
         .addToBackStack(null)
         .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `new Intent(Frag2.this,HelpLine.class);` Try this `new Intent(getContext(),HelpLine.class);`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, true);
            button = (ImageButton) view .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openHelpLine();
                }
            });
            }

    public void openHelpLine() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HelpLine.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (Kotlin version):

```
class Frag2 : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var button: ImageButton? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, false)
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2)
        button?.setOnClickListener(this)
        return view
    }

    private fun openHelpLine() {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), HelpLine::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        when (v) {
            button -> openHelpLine()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent needs Context as its first parameter.. 
context are of 2 types

1) Application Context

2) Activity context

**context is handle to the environment of Application running In.**

and here in your code context is Activity as fragment is part of Activity..

Fragment is not a context..

Activity is parent or container of fragment..
so context of fragment is always Activity ..

so for this you need to use `getActivity()` instead of Frag2.this